# Parsing csv file with vim

Tags: csv, vim

I have a large CSV file structured as follows:

```
CHINESE        TRANSLATION
我去上学。       Wǒ qù shàngxué. I am going to school. 上 ♦ on, on top of ♦ go to
我去过北京。     Wǒ qùguò Běijīng. I've been to Beijing. 京 -- ♦ national capital ♦ Beijing
....
```

The TRANSLATION column blends together three different informations: the pinyin, the English translation and additional information.  These three types of information are always present and always presented in the same way and separated by a dot.

What I want to achieve is to create three different columns from the TRANSLATION column, ie to get :

```
CHINESE         PINYIN             TRANSLATION             ADDITIONAL
我去上学。       Wǒ qù shàngxué.    I am going to school.    上 ♦ on, on top of ♦ go to
....
```

Using a vim macro, how can I do this ?

Comment: "large" in this case means several thousands of entries

Comment: I recommend using Tabular (https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)

Comment: It's not CSV (*comma*-separated values). Are columns separated by TAB characters, or are they aligned with spaces? Are different translations always separated by periods?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: yeah, sorry for the confusion.  The file is CSV (separated with commas), I just "pretty-formatted" it here for the sake of readability.

Comment: @RunningTurtle and do you want CSV as a *result* too? And should it be reusable solution or a one-time hack to handle one concrete CSV file? For some cases, a simple search-and-replace like :%s/\./","/g would suffice, but it's unreliable if CSV file can have quotes in quotes, unquoted values, multi-line values etc.. For reusable solution, I'd recommend some scripting language with a ready-to-use CSV module.

Comment: Several thousands is not hard at all, throw it in a hash map in JS (or Object as keys if you're not in an ES6 environment) and just match it.

Comment: is it not enough to replace dots by comma: sed 's/\./,/g' < input.csv

Comment: @JosefN: yes, that's what I ended up doing (also had to take question marks, exclamation marks and other quirks into account)... I guess the simplest solutions are sometimes the best and most easily overlooked ... Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You know your input best, should be able to come up with a workable `:substitute` yourself?!

Answer (score 2):

I think vim macros can handle this job, but executing a vim macro on a big file several thousand times is very slow. So if you just want your job done, I have just wrote a python script, and I think it could give you what you want.

```
import csv

# change 'in.csv' and 'out.csv' 
# to your exact file names.
with open('in.csv', 'r') as infile:
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(infile)
        for a, b in csvreader:
            line = a + ',' + ','.join(b.split('.'))
            outfile.writelines(line)
```

Comment: How about an awk version of it? which may ran inside the vim for large file without slowing.